# How to retrieve the categorical details in Wikidata

Tags: sparql, rdf, wikidata

I have a list of instances as follows.

```
myinstances = ['word2vec', 'tf-idf', 'dijkstra's algorithm']
```

For each `myinstance` in the above list, I want to find:

```
 1. What are the other instances of `myinstance`'s category (i.e. only one hop)
 2. What are the instances of `myinstance`'s category's category (i.e. two hops)
```

For example, if we consider `myinstance = word2vec`

1. What are the other instances of `myinstance`'s category (i.e. only one hop)?
   As shown in the figure below the other instances of its immediade ancestor is GloVe.
   [image]
2. What are the instances of `myinstance`'s category's category (i.e. two hops)? In other words, what are the instances of `embedding` (which is two hops away from `word2vec`) as shown the below figure.

[image]

I am just wondering if such query searches can be performed in sparql?

My current code is as follows.

```
SELECT * {
    VALUES ?searchTerm { "word2vec" "tf-idf" "dijkstra's algorithm" }
    SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "EntitySearch".
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org".
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:limit 1 .
        bd:serviceParam mwapi:search ?searchTerm.
        bd:serviceParam mwapi:language "en".
        ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item.
        ?num wikibase:apiOrdinal true.
    }
    ?item (wdt:P279|wdt:P31) ?type
}
```

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: Regarding 1. it's just finding other instances of the type you already have in the variable `?type`, so it's pretty much adding another triple pattern  `?otherItem (wdt:P279|wdt:P31) ?type .` such that the instances share the same type and indeed don't forget to select `?otherItem`. And indded a filter that avoids getting the same item makes sense: `filter(?item != ?otherItem)`, but I guess that's obvious.

Comment: Regarding 2: it's the same procedure, just add another triple pattern to simulate one more step or just add a step in the property path

Comment: something like this path might work, haven't tried it: `?otherItem (wdt:P279|wdt:P31)/^(wdt:P279|wdt:P31) ?type`. Might be easier for understanding to just use a proper triple pattern to get the super type first, and then get instances of this supertype.

Comment: @AKSW Thanks a lot for your valuable comments. I was able to successfully write the query for the 1st task based on your instructions in comment 1. However, I am not clear what you meant by comment 2. Could you please elaborate it with the code. I look forward to hearing from you. Thank you :)

Comment: You have to learn thinking of a graph, i.e. thinking of edges. You already have a visualization of the graph, so it's more or less trivial. An edge represents a triple, thus, each edge can be retrieved by a triple pattern. `?item (wdt:P279|wdt:P31) ?type .` is the edge to the type of the item. You said you want all instances of the supertype of the type, thus, you have to follow an outgoing edge to the supertype, thus, you have to add a triple pattern form `type` to the supertype. And I've also shown an more compact but less understandable way by means of the property path in my 3rd comment

Comment: @AKSW Thanks a lot for suggesting me property paths. When I run the proprety paths code (i.e. the 3rd comment), for `word2vec` I gor the following results; `word embedding`, `sentence embedding`, `knowledge graph embedding` etc. I am just wondering if it is possible to get the `leaf` nodes of the above results (in other words what are the algorithms involved with above results). I look forward to hearing from you. Thank you very much once again :)

Comment: not sure, but you can try this:`?item (wdt:P279|wdt:P31)/(wdt:P279|wdt:P31) ?superType .
  ?otherItem (wdt:P31|wdt:P279)* ?superType
  filter(?item != ?otherItem)
  filter not exists{?anotherItem (wdt:P279|wdt:P31) ?otherItem }` - it will avoid nodes having incoming edges of type `wdt:P279` or `wdt:P31`, so those are supposed to be leafs in the context of a hierarchy

Comment: @AKSW Thanks a lot for the wonderful answer. :)

Comment: @AKSW I am still learning the query you mentioned above. Suppose, if I have a node (e.g., Word2vec) and I want to see if this node have any incoming edges of type `wdt:P279` or `wdt:P31` how can I change your above code? I look forward to hearing from you. Thank you very much :)

Comment: `select * { ?s wdt:P279|wdt:P31  wd:Q22673982 . }`

Comment: @AKSW I am still experimenting with the queries you have mentioned above. Given a node (e.g., word embedding) I want to check whether it has any leaf nodes (leaf nodes are nodes that do not have any incoming edges of type `wdt:P279` or `wdt:P31`). Is it possible to do it in a wikidata query? Looking forward to hearing from you. Thank you very much once again :)

Comment: You already asked this before. And that's why I suggested (5 comments above yours) to use the filter: `filter not exists{?incomingNode (wdt:P279|wdt:P31) ?node }` - what does not work?

Comment: @AKSW Thanks a lot for query. When I run the above query for `word embedding` (`Q18395344`), I do not get any results. However, `word embedding` have two leaf nodes namely `word2vec` and `GloVe`. Is it possible to get only the `leaf nodes` of a given node (e.g., `word embedding`) using a wikidata query? I look forward to hearing from you. Thank you very much :)

Comment: I don't know which query you mean, sorry

Comment: @AKSW I am sorry if my explaination was not clear. I will explain my problem using a diffrent example. Suppose, I have the node `wd:Q29043227` (`embedding`). When I run the code; `SELECT * {
    ?s wdt:P279|wdt:P31 wd:Q29043227 .}`, I get 5 nodes as the results. However, the node `wd:Q18395344` in the results list is `not a leaf node`. Therefore, I am would like to know if there is a way to get `only the leaf nodes` (i.e. omitting `wd:Q18395344`). Please kindly let me know if my explaination is still not clear. I look forward to hearing from you. Thank you very much :)

Comment: and what does not work with the filter I suggested? I don't get it. Obviously, you have to adapt the variable names ... my suggestion was for a generic node which I called just `?node` for simplicity.

Comment: @AKSW Thanks a lot for the comment. Now I understand what you meant. Previously, I have assigned incorrect variable names. That is why I didn't get the expected results. I adapted the variable names correctly as you have suggested and now it works as I expected. Thanks a lot for all your valuable comments. I truly appreciate it.  Thank you very much :)

Comment: ok, very good. Now that you solved the problems, you could add the answers for all your questions where the answer is still missing. This could help other people to see the final answer.

Comment: @AKSW Thanks a lot. Sure, I will update the answers. Thank you very much once again :)